# How to check if an Eigen::Matrix4f is close to identity matrix?

Tags: matrix, eigen, floating-accuracy

Is there a good practice to check if my result Eigen::Matrix4f is almost identity? Since due to floating point errors I don't get some times exactly only zeros and ones.

One brute force method would be, to check each value in the matrix if it is between certain EPSILON and if just one of them fails, then it is not an identity matrix. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to define in what sense they shall be "close". There can be many different definitions of closeness, depending on your specific task. One of the most used is:

```
norm( A - I ) < eps
```

where `norm` is some [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). Most common are 2-norm, 1-norm, inf-norm and Frobenius norm.

Your method is also possible. It is equivalent to the method above with max-norm (where `norm(A) = max abs Aij`). It can be implemented in Eigen using:

```
(A - Matrix4f::Identity()).cwiseAbs().max() < eps;
```

**Update**:
Actually, in Eigen there is a special method to check that: [`isIdentity`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a540a2d7574d89c072f034147d8d0944e). You give it the threshold value:

```
A.isIdentity(eps)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't find the isIdentity function, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I believe it should be maxCoeff() instead of max():

```(A - Matrix4f::Identity()).cwiseAbs().maxCoeff()```